# Why is my pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm creating a class for pygame which will allow users to create textboxes for their game. My code doesn't reach the `mousebuttondown` part for some reason though. I'm attaching my whole code along with parts that I'm facing issues with.

**it doesn't print done**

```
def main(self, events, mousepos, id):
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.rect(id, mousepos):
                print("done")
```

**keeps printing no**

```
def rect(self, text_id, mousepos):
    x, y, width, height = self.dict_all[text_id]
    if ((x + width) > mousepos[0] > x) and ((y + height) > mousepos[1] > y):
        print("yes")
        return True
    else:
        print("no")
        return False
```

**whole code below, update was a method I was trying to make but didn't work for some reason.**

```
import pygame

pygame.font.init()


class textBox:
    def __init__(self, surface, id, color, width, height, x, y, antialias, maxtextlen):
        self.surface = surface
        self.id = id
        self.color = color
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.antialias = antialias
        self.maxtextlen = maxtextlen

        self.text_list = []
        self.text_list_keys = []
        self.currentId = 0
        self.click_check = False
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 20)
        self.dict_all = {}

        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, (self.color), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        # for i in self.text_list_keys:
        #     if self.id not in i:
        #         self.text_list_keys.append(self.id)
        #         self.text_list.append(tuple(self.id))
        #     else:
        #         self.nothing()
        self.dict_all[self.id] = tuple((self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

    def update(self, events, mousepos):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and ((self.x + self.width) > mousepos[0] > self.x) \
                    and ((self.y + self.height) > mousepos[1] > self.y):
                print("reached: " + mousepos)
                self.click_check = True
            else:
                self.click_check = False

            if self.click_check:
                print("1")
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    print("@")
                    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                        print("reached")
                        new_t = ""
                        for j in range(len(self.text_list)):
                            t = (self.text_list[j][0]).index(self.getId(self.currentId))
                            new_t = t
                        self.text_list[new_t].append("a")
                        self.surface.blit(self.font.render(f'{self.text_list[new_t]}', self.antialias, (0, 0, 0)),
                                          (self.x, self.y))

                    else:
                        print("this")

            else:
                pass

    def rect(self, text_id, mousepos):
        x, y, width, height = self.dict_all[text_id]
        if ((x + width) > mousepos[0] > x) and ((y + height) > mousepos[1] > y):
            print("yes")
            return True
        else:
            print("no")
            return False

    def getId(self, text_id):
        self.currentId = text_id

    def nothing(self):
        return False

    def main(self, events, mousepos, id):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if self.rect(id, mousepos):
                    print("done")
```

**test.py**

```
import pygame
from pygame_textbox import textBox

pygame.init()

win_width = 500
win_height = 500

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((win_width, win_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("test")

run = True
while run:
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    a = textBox(screen, 1, (255,  255, 255), 100, 30, 100, 100, True, 20)
    # a.getId(1)
    a.rect(1, mouse)
    a.main(events, mouse, 1)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd argument to the method main has to be the mouse position rather than the mouse buttons:

```py
run = True
while run:
    # [...]

    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    a.main(events, mouse_pos, 1)

    # [...]
```

While  [`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed) a sequence of booleans representing the state of all the mouse buttons, [`pygame.mouse.get_pos()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pos) returns the X and Y position of the mouse cursor.